# An example where $E\left[\lim_{n \to \infty}X_n\right] \neq \lim_{n \to \infty}E\left[X_n\right]$

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, random-variables

As in the title, what would be an example where $$E\left[\lim_{n \to \infty}X_n\right] \neq \lim_{n \to \infty}E\left[X_n\right]$$? with $E$ representing expectation and $X_n$ is random variable? (for limit of the left-hand side, this would be distribution limit/convergence)

Would this occur only for what one can conceive as very contrived?

Comment: It's not very complicated. Try $\Omega = [0,1]$ and $X_n$ of the form $c_n \mathbf{1}_{[a_n,b_n]}$.

Comment: @zhoraster Is $\Omega$ representing the set of outcomes containing only 0, 1 or interval $[0,1]$? Also what does $c_n 1_{[a_n,b_n]}$ supposed to mean? Is that probability density function, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider $(0,1)$ endowed with Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ (restricted to $(0,1)$) and

$$X_n(\omega) := n 1_{(0,n^{-1})}(\omega).$$